# handle recycled checkbox inside ListView with ResourceCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

i am loading Phone Contact Data into a ListView which has a TextView and a CheckBox as a row.

the problem i am facing is in handling CheckBox , once i check on any item in a ListView ,
it gets checked but when i scroll down the listView items gets check `automatically` for a new set of rows, this is happeing just because listview recycled the stuff but how i can handle this one for checkbox

i am using `ResourceCursorAdapter` and using bindView and newView methods.

i saw few threads in which they said to store the state of checkbox but they are `not for ResourceCursorAdapter` , so how will be the approach ?

so far i tried following [`based on RateListDemo of commonsware`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/FancyLists/RateList/src/com/commonsware/android/fancylists/six/RateListDemo.java)

```
 public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ContactListItemCache holder=(ContactListItemCache)row.getTag();

    if (holder==null) { 
    holder=new ContactListItemCache(row);
    row.setTag(holder);

    /** I really don't know what to set over here **/
    CheckBox cbox=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.contactCheck);
        cbox.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Log.d("Check check",position+"");

            }

        });

        /** I really don't know what to set over here too **/
        holder.selCheckBox =cbox;
        holder.selCheckBox.setTag(new Integer(position));

    }
return row;

}
```

*Here is my ContactListItemCache*

```
  final static class ContactListItemCache {
    public TextView nameView;
    public QuickContactBadge photoView;
    public CheckBox selCheckBox;
    public CharArrayBuffer nameBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(128);
    public CharArrayBuffer nameMiddleBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(128);
    public CharArrayBuffer nameFamilyBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(128);

    /** Following Changes I have Made **/
    ContactListItemCache(){}
    ContactListItemCache(View base){

        selCheckBox = (CheckBox)base.findViewById(R.id.contactCheck);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and came up with a workaround, although I'm not sure this is the best way to do it.

I followed this (rather good) series of tutorials http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview_listview
and implemented up to and including section 8. "Tutorial: Domain Model and Rows interaction"

Note that this doesn't use ResourceCursorAdapter.

From there, I modified the getModel() function and the Model class itself.  I changed the getModel() method to return a list of models that match the data from my database.  Here's some example code (most copied from the tutorial with example modifications).  Look out for the '// example of additional data' comments.  This shows the places that were modified to handle more data (if you want your List items to display more than just a CheckBox and TextView for example).

```
public class Model {

    private String name;
    private int exampleInt; // example of additional data
    private boolean selected;

    public Model(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.exampleInt= 0;
        selected = false;
    }

    public Model(String name, int exampleInt) {
        this.name = name;
        this.exampleInt= exampleInt;
        selected = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // example of additional data
    public int getExampleInt() {
        return exampleInt;
    }

    public void setExampleInt(int i) {
        this.exampleInt = i;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

Then, in your activity, modify the getModel() function to fill the list with the information from your database.  I'm pretending the example data (exampleInt) is held in the column "exampleint":

```
private List<Model> getModel() {
    //setContentView(R.layout.teamview);
    datasource.open();
    Cursor cursor = datasource.GetCursor();

    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

    while ( cursor.moveToNext() ) {
        list.add( get( cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( "name" ) ),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("exampleint" ) ) ) );  // example of additional data
    }

    // Initially select one of the items
    //list.get(1).setSelected(true);
    datasource.close();
    return list;
}
```

You'll have to modify the get() function as well which returns a new Model instance if you want the additional exampleInt:

```
private Model get(String name, int example) {
    return new Model(name, example);
}
```

Finally, in your arrayadapter (in the tutorial it is the InteractiveArrayAdapter), change the ViewHolder to match your list item layout. In this example I'll pretend it's called 'youritemlayoutxml', and has an additional TextView (R.id.exampleint) to display our new exampleInt.  Also modify the getView(...) function to set up the view with the required information:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView textName;
    protected TextView textExampleInt; // example of additional data
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.youritemlayoutxml, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.textExampleInt= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.exampleint);  // example of additional data
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
        viewHolder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                                .getTag();
                        element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                    }
                });
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.textName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.textExampleInt.setText(Integer.toString(list.get(position).getExampleInt()));  // example of additional data
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
    return view;
}
```

I believe everything else should be unmodified from the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

commonsWare has a nice example to handle this:

[RateListDemo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/FancyLists/RateList/src/com/commonsware/android/fancylists/six/RateListDemo.java)

Hope this helps.